# Sonar complaining about static assignment

Tags: java, sonarqube

I have this assignment to a static variable that reads data off a file:

```
public static final Map<String, Integer> MY_DATA_RESOURCE;
static {
    MY_DATA_RESOURCE = parseAndTransformFile();
  }
```

I want this variable to be publicly accessible to all classes and I want to initialize it with this method call. Doing this triggers a Sonar complaint "Mutable fields should not be "public static" though.

I have that parseAndTransform method which I do not want to call directly multiple times and trigger a read each time and I also want to avoid adding a getter method which is basically adding a third layer to data access.

Do I have any other options here?

Comment: Try to remove final and see sonar violations.

Comment: That final is there because of a sonar complaint

Comment: `public static final Map<String, Integer> MY_DATA_RESOURCE = Collections.unmodifiableMap(parseAndTransformFile());`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

However your field is declared as `final`, map itself is not immutable and you can still `put()` some items to it (unless you are using some `Collections.unmodifiableMap()` - but anyway you don't know this by interface) and that's why Sonar is complaining

Try to wrap the `Map` in some immutable class implementation and change the type of the field to this class. This has this additional advantage, that if in the future you will decide that you need to add some additional meta-data about file (like creation time) instead of sculpting in the `Map` structure you can easily add a field to your own mapper class

Comment: I like that idea. Not having a default type for a business-logic heavy field sounds like better practice too

Comment: Although that has the downside of making access more verbose I just realized

Comment: what do you mean by 'verbose'?

Comment: If I hide the map in a POJO I also need extra steps to get items from it. Using Collections.unModifiableMap worked though

Answer (score 1):

You could use Guava's [immutable maps](https://guava.dev/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap.html):

```
public static final ImmutableMap<String, Integer> MY_DATA_RESOURCE = 
    ImmutableMap.copyOf(yourMethodCall());
```

You also could use a static method, not field:

```
private static final Map<String, Integer> MY_DATA_RESOURCE;

static {
  MY_DATA_RESOURCE = parseAndTransformFile();
}

public static Map<String, Integer> myDataResource() {
  return Collections.unmodifiableMap(MY_DATA_RESOURCE);
}
```

with this approach, you could also eventually decide to parse and transform the file lazily (when someone inquired about its contents) rather than in the `static {}` block.

Comment: I like idea with static method however seems that recreating every time `unmodifableMap` instance is overhead - I would suggest exposing some `getValueByKey` method that would expose `Map.get()`

Comment: unmodifiableMap is cheap to create - it doesn't actually copy the content over. Conversely, you could use an ImmutableMap and not worry about unmodifiables